# Can't connect to my EC2 windows anymore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Before I'd traveled for 3 weeks, my connection to EC2 windows - ec2-54-186-219-106.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com - was perfect. In this period, I was away, on vacation, and didn't connect to it. Now, I try to connect via RDP from my MacBook and see the message:"Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons: 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote computer is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the network". I've checked some forums and got some advice like: reboot my instance, change my security group, add port 80 to my security group, but nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: Did you stop the instance when you were on vacation? Is an elastic IP attached to the windows instance? Did you check in AWS console if the IP of the windows changed after you returned from vacation?

Comment: @helloV, I didn't stop the instance. On Monday, I,ve rebooted the instance and updated in the RDP the new IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve my problem: I've attached an IP to my instance, and it starts working again. I hope it helps someone who is facing a similar situation. That's all folks!